# CHAR column not recognizing text values in R data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table with an 'id' column that needs to be treated as CHAR but only identifies numeric values.

```
> str(relatorio)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  98010 obs. of  3 variables
 $ id      : chr  NA "9074214401" "19136560472" "55171117420" ...
 $ SITUACAO: chr  "ATIVA" "ATIVA" "ATIVA" "ATIVA" ...
 $ curso   : chr  "Não" "Não" "Não" "Não" ...

> relatorio[id == "08789441419"]
Empty data.table (0 rows and 3 cols): id,SITUACAO,curso

> relatorio[id == 08789441419]
       id SITUACAO curso
1: 8789441419    ATIVA   Não
```

I've tried converting the column using as.character() but nothing work. I have tried reading the table from .csv and .xlsx but still get the same thing. Any thoughts on why the 'id' columns does not recognize the string vale "08789441419"?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess, since your data is insufficient to be reproducible, is that your `== "08789..."` is assuming that your actual `id` begins with `0`, whereas perhaps it actually begins with `8`: R, when it is comparing the character `id` with your numeric `08789441419` converts your comparison to the string `"8789441419"` (no leading zero).

Comment: As to your concern, the `str` shows without a doubt that your `id` field is `chr`, so it is character; `as.character` will do nothing. Try `dt[id == "8789441419"]`.

Comment: Yes, @r2evans, that was it!! Without the leading 0 it worked. Thank you very much, I was struggling with this and the solution was so simple. Thank you!